# Session state has created a session id, but cannot save it because the response was already flushed by the application

Tags: c#, asp.net, exception, session-state

I have researched regarding this exception..most of the solution specifies to add some content in global.asax file.. But in my solution i dont find global.asax... But still i'm getting this exception.. Kindly help me in this..

Thanks

Comment: But in my solution i don't find global.asax ??? there is no such file in your asp.net project?

Comment: @StefanP.
ya.. Its not available..

Comment: You can go ahead and add it using Add new item

Answer (score 0):

try this, add this tag in web.config file

```
 <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="30480" requestLengthDiskThreshold="30480"/>
```